# PL/SQL Reg Exp found last number and split

Tags: regex, string, plsql, split

How do I use reg expression to found last number in a string and then everything on the right hand side in to column c1 and from the last number everything on the left + 1 character go into column c2 ?

**e.g 1**

```
string = 1234john4345 this is a test.
```

Result

```
c1 = 1234john4345  
c2 = this is a test.
```

**e.g 2**

```
string = 1234john4345a this is a test.
```

Result

```
c1 = 1234john4345a  
c2 = this is a test.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select test
    --Group 1: Match everything up to the last digit, and one other character
    --Group 2: Everything after group 1
    ,regexp_replace(test, '(.*[[:digit:]].)(.*)', '\1') c1
    ,regexp_replace(test, '(.*[[:digit:]].)(.*)', '\2') c2
from
(
    select '1234john4345 this is a test.' test from dual union all
    select '1234john4345a this is a test' test from dual
);
```